# Fastest way to xml parsing in Java

Tags: xml, multithreading, parsing, parallel-processing, java-8

I have a homework about xml parsing. I have many xml file. Every xml file include too many line and tags. Here I must parse them and write .txt file with xml's file name. This needs to be done quickly. Faster the better.

How can I parse many xml files and write many text files using multi thread or java8 features(Lambda Expressions,Parallelism etc. ) in java as fast as I can?

First I try to SAX Parser for this. Here is my code:

What can I add to this code to work faster?  or Anyone know another way to work faster?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t see any way for a fundamental performance improvement, but you didn’t explain why you think your program is too slow. Besides that, you should clean up the logic first, i.e. how your code deals with nested elements. Each time you’re descending into an element, you are dropping the `StringBuilder` and its content, but when ascending, you might reuse the `StringBuilder` of the nested element. You might get away with that when `<charParams>` never contains other elements, but that’s not a reliable program logic. And statements like `fullText += "";` make no sense at all…

Comment: "Faster the better" is never a sensible requirement. You have to balance it against development cost. Otherwise you'll be writing custom XML parsers in assembly language.